# Can't invoke Lambda function AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

My Lambda function in node.js:

```
console.log('Loading function');

  exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
  context.succeed("Hello " + event.key1);
  };
```

I want a client (my laptop) to send an object that contains the value "world" to this lambda function. The function adds "Hello " and returns "Hello world".
I used cmd with curl with the following statement:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"key1":"world"}' https://blablablabla.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/helloworld2
```

But I only get back {"message":"internal server error"}

Any ideas? Are there any other ways to send the "world" value. Maybe javascript in a html file or a simple java app in Eclipse? The lambda function itself is fine. I successfully tested it with a test event.

Comment: Check the CloudWatch Logs for this function to see what the actual internal server error is. Also what is your API Gateway mapping template?

Comment: You can also try testing your API in the API Gateway console, which might give you some additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function seems fine. But you are missing the `Content-Type` header on your cURL command. Do it as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"key1\": \"World\"}" https://blablablabla.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/helloworld2
```

You can double check this requirement in [this AWS documentation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-new-post)

Update: Try with this function (I only added the callback parameter)

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
    callback(null, {"Hello": event.key1});
};
```